# GraphQL: Standard or Standish Filtering Arguments?

Tags: graphql

I'm new to GraphQL and still getting my bearing, so I apologize if this is known science or a well trod area.

Is there a standard set of arguments a GraphQL server developer should implement if they're providing field arguments for filtering?  For example, as a GraphQL server developer, if I wanted to implement a greater-than or less-than API, I might do any of the following

```
{
    author (min_date_of_birth: '...date...')  {
         //... fields ...
    }
}

{
    author (date_of_birth_greater_than: '...date...')  {
         //... fields ...
    }
}

{
    author_by_birthday (date: '...date...', operator: 'gt')  {
         //... fields ...
    }
}

// etc...
```

In my research GraphQL itself [appears to be neutral](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/341) on this subject, but it seems slightly off that a graph *query language* wouldn't have a standard or standardish set of filtering arguments.

Are there standard filtering arguments that a GraphQL server developer should use?  Or is this something that's left up to each server developer with no official, or even defacto, standards?